# Is there a way to open folders in the OS explorer?

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

**What I want:** 
To open the OS (windows) folder to a specific path/directory/file. 
I do not want to use *tkinter.filedialog*. I'm looking for something to open the native file explorer. The same we use to navigate on drive/disk.

**What I tried:**
I searched on google about this with multiple key words but what I fount was just *tkinter.filedialog*. I know it is possible because Windows and Linux can show it. So what I want is just to use that one to a specific path.

**Code:**
The code is not complicated. I work on a project to edit some files metadata and for debugging I listed all files one by one and if one file get an error I make a button what will show me the file path on console. Now I need just that button to open OS folder on that path.

```py
# Import
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, filedialog
import os

# Global variables
root = Tk()
frm_status = None

# Main
class main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        global frm_status
        self.master = master

        master.wm_title("Example Code")
        master.wm_geometry("300x150")

        Button(master, text="Select files", command=lambda:Logic.AskPath("files")).pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="top")
        frm_status = Frame(master)
        frm_status.pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="top")

# Logc
class Logic:
    def AskPath(type):
        if type.lower() == "files":
            path = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title="Select witch files...",
                                               filetypes=(("TEXT", "*.txt"), ("ALL FILES", "*.*")))
        elif type.lower() == "folder":
            # Somethin similar code here
            pass
        Logic.SmartDetect(path)

    def SmartDetect(path):
        # Make shore is not tuple and also a directory
        if isinstance(path, str) and os.path.isdir(path):
            # Some logics here to check compatibility for all files from path
            pass
        else:
            # In case on tuple are more the one files selected
            for f in path:
                # Some logic to check some files compatibility
                # ....
                # At the end is something similar like this
                Logic.StatusUpdate(f)

    def StatusUpdate(path):
        # A small logic to have the ideea how my button will loke and do
        Button(frm_status, text=os.path.basename(path), anchor="w", command=lambda:print(path)
               ).pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="top")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Solution code on definition:** (thanks to @lemon)

```
    def StatusUpdate(path):
        # A small logic to have the ideea how my button will loke and do
        Button(frm_status, text=os.path.basename(path), anchor="w",
               command=lambda:os.system(f'cmd /c "start {os.path.dirname(path)}"')
               ).pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="top")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your mean just open the folder by command line?

You can use 'ii' in PowerShell.

Comment: What do you mean **ii**? Cand you provide an example please?

Comment: @ASI 'ii' command will open specific folder in windows.
eg. "ii ./"

Comment: On CMD **ii** is not recognized

Comment: yep, it is not valid in cmd, but you can try it in powershell

Comment: Not helping... I try to found a way to open with default tools from OS if is possible. powershell need to be instaled...

Comment: haha~ by default PowerShell is installed on windows 10. btw, you also can use "start" command in CMD to open a specific folder.

Comment: thanks dude XD... CMD >> start "path/to/the/folder" is working perfect. Now I need jut to found a way to send commands to CMD from my app. Is not like was solved the problem, but is something then zero informations from google. So I will accept your answer like a good one thx.